# Why do my java graphics lag so much?

Tags: java, linux, performance, lag

I know there are already many questions about slow java graphics, but none of them have solved my problem. The lag in my program seems very unnatrual, and has no explanation as far as I can tell.

I am creating a 2D game, and it has terrible lag. At first I thought it was from all the graphics being drawn in the game, so I did many things to try and improve performance, but none of them changed anything.

To make sure it was the game that was causing lag, I made a very simple (badly written) program that just moves a square across the screen.

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main extends JPanel{

static Main main = new Main();

int x;
int y;

public static void main(String[]args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(main);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while(true){
        main.update();
        main.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public void update(){
    x++;
    y++;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
}

}
```

To my suprise, this simple program lags very badly too! I have been coding the game on linux (ubuntu GNOME 14.10), but I have run it on my Windows 7 partition as well, and it doesn't change the performance. I have also updated all my graphics drivers. My computer can also run other java programs such as Minecraft with no lag at all. I even tried importing the project file for this tutorial into eclipse and running it and it ran fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ar0hTsb9sxM

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent` and make sure to call `super.paintComponent` when you do.  Don't use a `while` loop like this, you can get a better (and safer) result using a Swing `Timer`.

Comment: And make use of the Event Thread.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with ubuntu as it runs fine on Windows.  You could consider using a `BufferStrategy` to take control of the paint process or using a dedicated gaming framework

Comment: You might also consider investigating time driven animation over linear animation (the object moves a given distance over a given time), it will allow the system to calculate the position based on the current "frame"/time

Comment: After playing around, I found that 60fps was giving me some trouble (it would appear to speed up and slow down), but this could be because my system is a dog.  When I reduced it to 25fps, it worked seamlessly...

Comment: Another choice might be to use `repaint(int, int, int, int)` to define the area you want updated instead of updating the whole screen...

Comment: Maybe it's just some strange interaction with the monitor refresh frequency (or whatever) as it happens to me close to 60 FPS as well. The CPU is idle (no idea about the GPU which really does the work), painting more such objects changes nothing nor making them bigger does. I didn't try `BufferStrategy`, but none of the other tips above helped.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have tried all your suggestions and they have had no effect. But I will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: I think something is definitely up, I recently tried FreePlane (a swing based app), on Ubuntu and it is unnaturally laggy.

Answer (score 7):

I put `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` in my render method which appears to fix it. However you should put a `If os is linux` before that.

Comment: I know I shouldn't say "wow" and "thanks", but after hunting this for hours, I do owe you a big Thank you.