# Why is my image motion so choppy when moving it with keybindings?

Tags: java, linux, swing

so I made this image drawing class, when I press the a or d key the motion at first is very choppy but after a second or so it becomes kinda smooth. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GameWindow extends JPanel {
    Image map;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    boolean isLeft = false, isRight = false;
    Action left;
    Action right;
    Action hleft;
    Action hright;
    public GameWindow(BufferedImage map){
        this.map = map.getScaledInstance(map.getWidth()*4, map.getHeight()*4, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        left = new Left();
        right = new Right();
        hleft = new HLeft();
        hright = new HRight();
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        Timer t = new Timer(42, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(isLeft && !isRight){
                    x-=5;
                } else if (!isLeft && isRight) {
                    x+=5;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed D"), "s move left");
        getActionMap().put("s move left", left);

        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"), "s move right");
        getActionMap().put("s move right", right);

        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "h move left");
        getActionMap().put("h move left", hleft);

        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "h move right");
        getActionMap().put("h move right", hright);

        t.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(map, x, y, null);
    }
    public class Left extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isLeft=true;
            //System.out.println("TEST");
        }
    }
    public class Right extends  AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isRight = true;
        }
    }
    public class HRight extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isRight = false;
        }
    }
    public class HLeft extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isLeft = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried searching what causes choppy motion, but the only thing that I could find was starting a timer instead of moving the image in the keybind / actionlistener, but It's still choppy

EDIT: I use Java 21.0.2, and I run Debian 12. I've contacted some friends, on some it runs smoothly (Windows, Arch) while on others (my pc and, Kali) it stutters.

Comment: Try reducing the distance (ie 1-2 pixels instead of 5) and increase the frequency of updates (ie 21 or 16 milliseconds) (actually, I just change the delay to 16 milliseconds and that seems to have smoothed it out just fine)

Comment: Instead of using seperate `boolean` flags, you could make use of an `enum` and a `Set` to determine which keeps are currently active

Comment: Increasing the frequency helped smoothing it out after the first second of me holding a key but during the first second it is still very choppy. As for the enum, I will change it to use it, but I doubt that it will help with the motion

Comment: I can reproduce this.  Regardless of the timer interval, I see choppy motion for roughly the first half second, each time a key is pressed.

Comment: Interestingly, if I comment out the getInputMap().put methods for the key released events, the animation becomes steadily worse—less than two frames per second.  This is Java 21.0.1 on Debian, with Intel integrated graphics.  (I doubt the graphics hardware is the issue, as I’ve written many JavaFX applications that run smoothly on it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Why do my java graphics lag so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370630/why-do-my-java-graphics-lag-so-much)

Apparently putting `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()` fixes the issue, although I'm not quite sure why.

Putting this here in case someone else stumbles into this issue.

Comment: Good find.  And worth noting that this is apparently only an issue in Linux, though I wonder if it would hurt to simply do sync() on all platforms.